# Parameter Estimation for First Order System

Tags: measurements, modeling, control-theory, systems-engineering

I would like to get a simple estimation of the parameters for a humidity chamber system. The humidity chamber has one constant inflow ($k_1$) and and outflow which depends on the humidity of a neighbor humidity chamber (diffusion, modeled as $k_2(RH_{ext} - RH)$. $RH$ is the humidity of the chamber, $RH_{ext}$ is the humidity of the external chamber. I have the following system description (first order):
$$
\frac{dRH}{dt} = k_1 + k_2(RH_{ext} - RH)
$$

Now, I have measurement data for $RH$ (output) and $RH_{ext}$ (input). $k_1$ could be seen as a second (constant) input. I would like to estimate the parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ in a simple manner (maybe least-square based) using my (discrete) measurement data in Matlab, but I don't know how I could proceed. Use the system identification toolbox? Other ways?

Comment: Hi Fabian, welcome to engineering.SE.  Our site supports [Latex style equation typesetting](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307/how-can-i-use-mathjax-latex-to-typeset-equations-on-this-site?cb=1); I've edited your post to use it.

Comment: What type of measurement data do you have?  Is it $RH$ vs. time with all other parameters constant?  If so, you can simply integrate the equation and do a 3 parameter curve fit ($k_1$, $k_2$, and the integration constant).

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks very much for the edit and your answer. $RH_{ext}$ isn't a constant as well. Your approach seems clever, but I'm not so sure about how to do this in practice. You would simply try to fit $RH(t)$ to $f(t)=k_1 t + k2\left(\int RH_{ext} - \int RH \right)+c$, by using the numerical integrations $\int RH_{ext}$ and $\int RH$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have [MATLAB](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/), so it's a simple linear fit:

- From your vector $RH(t)$, compute $\frac{d RH}{dt}$ by numerical differentiation
- Create a matrix $A$ with ones on the first column and the values of $RH_{ext}(t) - RH(t)$ on the second column
- Create a matrix $B$ with the values of $\frac{d RH}{dt}$ (use 0 as the initial value)
- Your result vector is given $A$ \ $B$

  `dRH = [0; diff(RH)./diff(t)];`

  `A = [ones(size(RH)) RH_ext-RH];`

  `k = A\dRH; % k(1) is k1, k(2) is k2`

Comment: Just to emphasize the point; $A\setminus B$ uses Matlab's [left division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) operator which is used to solve a system of linear equations described in matrix notation.

Comment: @ChrisMueller yes, that's right. Thanks for the clarification